# Search in one attribute OR another one in a same Model

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am trying to use Haystack and would like to set a search engine :

In a same model, I would like to be able to either search in `attribute a` **OR** search in `attribute b`.

My model's structure is the following:

```
Datas : a
        b
        date
```

I tried the following code in my `search_indexes.py` :

```
class ADatasIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    a = indexes.CharField(model_attr='a')
    date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Datas

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())

class BDatasIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    b = indexes.CharField(model_attr='b')
    date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date')


    def get_model(self):
        return Datas

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

But without any success :

```
ImproperlyConfigured("Model '%s' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` hand
ling it. Please exclude either '%s' or '%s' using the 'HAYSTACK_EXCLUDED_INDEXES
' setting." % (model, self.indexes[model], index))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Model '<class 'mainsite.models.Datas'>' has more than one 'SearchIndex`` handling it. Please exclude either '<ma
insite.search_indexes.ADatasIndex object at 0x03176DF8>' or '<mains
ite.search_indexes.BDatasIndex object at 0x031AD8F0>' using the 'HAYSTACK
_EXCLUDED_INDEXES' setting.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting results from two SearchIndex classes for the same model.

You only need **one** SearchIndex, and then **both** fields will be put on the data template.

```
class DatasIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    a = indexes.CharField(model_attr='a')
    b = indexes.CharField(model_attr='b')
    date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Datas

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Then, inside your template directory, create a file:

search/indexes/myapp/datas_text.txt

In that file goes:

```
{{ object.a }}
{{ object.b }}
```

along with any other fields that you want to search on.

The haystack documentation for this is [here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#handling-data):

Comment: Ok but maybe I explained my problem badly : I would like to be able to search only in attribute a or only in the attribute b or both. Your solution is only working for the both attributes ( a AND b) search.

Comment: Yes, perhaps we are not understanding each other. Using this method if you search for "erwan" it would return any Datas object that had "erwan" in field "a" or in field "b". Try running ./manage.py rebuild_index to be sure that everything is in your index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy model as mentioned in this haystack [issue](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/595).

```
class BDatas(Datas):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Then in BDatasIndex

```
def get_model(self):
    return BDatas
```